# How do I print the correspond key of a value of dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have already build a dictionary.Here is my dictionary:

```
mydict = {'to': 12, 'and': 35, 'Python': 26, 'for': 49}
```

I want to sort this dictionary by value (from max to min) and print result like this:

```
for 49
and 35
Python 26
to 12
```

I don't know how to do it.Any help will be appreciated!
I have tried:

```
  (1)  for key,value in mydict.items():
        print(key,sorted(mydict.values(),reverse=True))  #int is not iterable
```

(2)use dict.keys() and dict.values(), but I don't know how to print correspond keys.

(3)I tried to build a list for value and build a new dictionary from value's list.But I don't know how to do it.

(4)try to convert int to string,but it can't be converted!
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```py
sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

So the full code would be:

```py
for key, value in sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True):
    print(key, value)
```

Python's built-in [sorted()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#sorted) function has an optional `key` parameter, that you can pass a lambda function (going in depth here would break the scope of the question, but it is advisable that you google it until you have a rough idea) or *any* function really, that will be passed each element in turn. Since in your case every element is in the form of `(key, value)`, we use lambda to extract the `value` part of each element and sort accordingly.